# React Next Graphql query - How to get nested data?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql

I want to access nested object data on my Next app from GraphQL query. I can get level 0 data but not more than that.

```js
import { apolloCon } from "../con/apolloCon";
import { GET_ALL_POSTS } from "../graphql/queries";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

export default function Home({ posts }) {
  console.log('posts', posts);
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1>Welcome to blog app with nextjs</h1>
      <div className={styles.postsWrapper}>
        {posts &&
          posts?.map((post) => {
            return (
              <div className={styles.card} key={post.id}>
                <h1>{post.Title}</h1>
                <h3>{post.Description}</h3>
             
                <br></br>
                <p>{post.Content}</p>
              </div>
            );
          })}

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { data, loading, error } = await apolloCon.query({
    query: GET_ALL_POSTS,
  });
  return {
    props: {
      posts: data.Articles
    },
  };
}
```

Query -

```js
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const GET_ALL_POSTS = gql`
query MyQuery {
  Articles {
    Title
    id
    slug
    Content
    Description
    Post_Category {
      Categories_id {
        Title
        id
      }
    }
    Featured_Image {
      filename_download
    }
  }
}
`;
```

I want post_category Title for my blog post. I can get other data as expected but not the post_category title. How can I get the nested data ?

```
    {
  "data": {
    "Articles": [
      {
        "Title": "What is Lorem Ipsum?",
        "slug": "what-is-lorem-ipsum",
        "Content": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. \n\nIt was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
        "Description": "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
        "Featured_Image": {
          "filename_disk": "454952bc-b56d-4c5a-8f83-6bf74d36651e.jpg",
          "filename_download": "DSCF5418-2 - Copydfgdfg.jpg"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Articles_Categories": [
      {
        "Categories_id": {
          "Title": "Entertainment",
          "Content": "fgdfgdfgdfgdfg",
          "Slug": "entertainment"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]
I searched everywhere but can not find the answer.

Comment: Could you add your schema types for `Post_Category` an `Categories_id`?

Comment: Hi. I dont understand your question..

Comment: You didn't post your schema, therefore it's impossible to tell whether Post_Category and Categories_id are an object, or a list of objects.